# How to grab a part of text from source code of a page

Tags: php

I want to grab a part of source code that i received using `file_get_contents`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
var minFlashVersion = '9,0,124';
var playerWidth = 760;
var playerHeight = 554;
var playerFallbackFile = 'URL';
</script>
```

I want to grab that URL part of `var playerFallbackFile = 'URL';`

Can you please help me how to do that in php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236942/');
if (preg_match("/var playerFallbackFile = '(.*?)'/", $data, $match))
{
    echo $match[1]; // "URL"
}
else
{
    die('playerFallbackFile not found');
}
```